How to check for failed convergence when using astropy fitting (specifically LevMarLSQFitter())
The sequence:
fit_something = fitting.LevMarLSQFitter()
fitted = fit_something(initial_guess_and_model,x,y,acc=accuracy,maxiter=maximumum_iterations) 

Will provide a fitted model, and in the dictionary "fit_info" there will be a lot of interesting information.
But I do not seem to find a simple way to answer the question: was convergence reached?
This would be answered by the returned paramters of scipy.optimize.leasts, namely:
ier
mesg
(this function seems to be called internally by astropy.modeling.fitting.LevMarLSQFitter
if I understand well)
How could I get this information?

So by looking at the documentation and source you can come up with this. I took the example of 1d Gaussian model fitting. The docs of the fitter tells you that the information from the last fitting is returned through the fit_info dictionary. So if you have the fit as given here
fit_t = fitting.LevMarLSQFitter()
t = fit_t(t_init, x, y, maxiter=200)

print(fit_t.fit_info['ierr'], fit_t.fit_info['message'])

yields the following.

3 Both actual and predicted relative reductions in the sum of squares
are at most 0.000000 and the relative error between two consecutive
iterates is at most 0.000000

The ierr==3 indicates that the fit converged. Hope it helps.

Thanks a lot, I must admit to my shame that in the meantime I had found the solution myself. What is one supposed to do in this case? delete the question? Anyway, the problem for me was that the documentation of scipy.optimize.leastsq link referred to "ier" and "mesg", while the names that astropy fitter returns are, as you correctly pointed out, ierr and message. I had to discover this inspecting the dictinfo dictionary.

Usually people answer their own question so there is a record of that. Anyways glad this is resolved.
